# KSQL Table-Table Left outer Join emit same join result more than once

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

using KSQL, and performing left outer join, i can see the result of my join sometime emitted more than once.

In other words, the same join result is emitted more than once. I am not talking about, a version of the join with the null value on the right side and a version without the null value. Literally the same record that result from a join is emitted more than once.

I wonder if that is an expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

the general answer is yes. kafka is an at-least-once system.
more specifically, a few scenarios can result in duplication:

1. consumers only periodically checkpoint their positions. a consumer crash can result in duplicate processing of some range or records
2. producers have client-side timeouts. this means the producer may think a request timed out and re-transmit while broker-side it actually succeeded.
3. if you mirror data between kafka clusters thats usually done with a producer + consumer pair of some sort that can lead to more duplication.

are you seeing any such crashes/timeouts in your logs?

there are a few kafka features you could try using to reduce the likelihood of this happening to you:

1. set `enable.idempotence` to true in your producer configs (see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) - incurs some overhead
2. use transactions when producing - incurs overhead and adds latency
3. set `transactional.id` on the producer in case your fail over across machines - gets complicated to manage at scale
4. set `isolation.level` to `read_committed` on the consumer - adds latency (needs to be done in combination with 2 above)
5. shorten `auto.commit.interval.ms` on the consumer - just reduces the window of duplication, doesnt really solve anything. incurs overhead at really low values.

Comment: How come setting “exactly_once” as processing garantee do not solve it ?

Comment: "ksql.streams.processing.guarantee": "exactly_once"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878221/does-ksql-support-kafka-stream-processing-guarantees/57899003#57899003

Comment: @MaatDeamon - there's no magic, only overhead. that setting will (if i read the docs correctly) simply set all the configurations i provided above for all producers and consumers that are under ksql's control. note that even in the official docs - https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/processing-guarantees/#exactly-once-semantics - you are warned that to truly get exactly once even the upstream/downstream clients outside of ksql's control need to be properly configured. and you should really measure the performance impact vs the damage of dups